# Main row heading colours when odd/even CSS in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have an expand/collapse table that automatically adjusts the odd/even row colours (dark grey and light grey) when expanding/collapsing..

What I am trying to achieve is that for some particular rows, I need to apply a background-colour (the class I used for this is mainRow).. However, because of my Javascript functions, I believe this is making the CSS to not perform as expected.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/JNQx4/1/

**HTML:**

```
<table class="tbl tbl--highlight stripes half-mb">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="mainRow">
        <td class="ShowMe">+ 0000111</td>
        <td>0000111</td>
        <td>0000111</td>
        <td>0000111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="itsHidden" class="visuallyhidden">
        <td>0000222</td>
        <td>0000222</td>
        <td>0000222</td>
        <td>0000222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0000333</td>            
        <td>0000333</td>
        <td>0000333</td>
        <td>0000333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0000444</td>
        <td>0000444</td>
        <td>0000444</td>
        <td>0000444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mainRow">
        <td class="ShowMe">+ 0000555</td>            
        <td>0000555</td>
        <td>0000555</td>
        <td>0000555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="itsHidden2" class="visuallyhidden">
        <td>0000666</td>            
        <td>0000666</td>
        <td>0000666</td>
        <td>0000666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0000777</td>            
        <td>0000777</td>
        <td>0000777</td>
        <td>0000777</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
th {
    min-width: 22px;
}
.stripes tbody > tr.odd {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.stripes li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.tbl {
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 2;
    clear: both;
}
.tbl th, .tbl td {
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
.tbl th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
.tbl--highlight tbody tr:hover {
    background: #d4e8fc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tbl--input td {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.half-mb {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

.visuallyhidden {
  display: none;
}

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
  display: block;
}

.mainRow {
 background-color: #0c5cac;  
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    function stripeTable(){
         $("table.stripes tr").removeClass("odd");
         $("table.stripes tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd"); 
    }
    stripeTable();

    $(".ShowMe").click(function() {

        $("#itsHidden").toggleClass("visuallyhidden");
        $("#itsHidden2").toggleClass("visuallyhidden");
        stripeTable();
    });
});
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: why are you confusing yourself by using class .odd there is :odd and :even pseudo selector.

Comment: Because that is what was suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040165/html-table-alternate-row-colours-with-hidden-rows

Comment: so you are combing different q/a and getting your job done?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar - what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure about what is really your problem.

If it is that you want your mainRow rows to be always blue, it's just a problem of specifity in your CSS. Both odd class and mainRow class set a background, and the odd selector has more specifity.

The easy solution is to add an important in the later

```
.mainRow {
    background-color: #0c5cac !important;  
}
```

There are people that say that using !important is a bad habit. But, as everything in life, I think that sometimes it is the easier way to solve an issue, and this is probably one of those cases.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNQx4/3/)